# Opposite behaviour in IE browser than Firefox and Chrome

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am developing the MVC application with razor syntax.

I am checking whether the owner of the comment and the loggedin user is same or not. 
If its a same then, I can show the delete button in front of that comment so he(logged-In user) can delete it.

below code performs this action

```
@{ 

    int loggedEmployeeId = (int)Session["loggedEmpId"];
}
      @if (loggedEmployeeId == @item.CommentedBy.Id)
     {
     <input type="button" id="comment@(item.Id)" class="deleteComment" value="Delete" />
     }
```

The above code works fine in Chrome and Mozilla but it works exactly apposite in the IE8.
The owner cant delete own comments but can delete others comments.

Whats the issue ?

Comment: Where does `loggedEmployeeId` come from? You present server-side code here, it doesn't make any sense to me, having different behavior in different browsers.. strange

Comment: Not sure if it will fix the issue, but you don't need the @ before `item.CommentedBy.Id` in your if clause

Comment: Could you show us the generated HTML? If there's a difference in browser behavior, it's because they interpret the generated HTML differently. From the HTML we might be able to backtrack the error in your server-side code.